# Allow hold block to unblock more than one agent type

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

So, I'm currently sending two different agents (each from their own source blocks) to a common queue. In that queue I use agent comparison in order to prioritize one agent over another.

View descriptive Image here:
[image]

However, in an upcoming hold-block, I cannot seem to unblock the next unit in the queue which is a different agent-type from the first (even though I have set it to "isBlocked = False" when the previous unit exited seize-delay-release). After that, the agent type that first entered service is the only one that can operate throughout the simulation. The other agent-type is stuck in the queue.

Any ideas on how I can get the other agent-type through the Hold-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hold block will work independently of the agent types in the queue ahead of it.

You should not be using `isBlocked = false` to 'open ' or 'close' the hold.  This code simply returns if the hold block is blocked or not.

[image]

You should use `block` for blocking and `unblock` for unlbocking

[image]
[image]

Here is a small working example where

- the hold block is set to initially blocked = false
- blocking the hold on the On Enter code of the hold block using `self.block()`
- unblocking the hold at the last delay using the On Exit code with `hold.unblock()`

and most importantly it uses two different agent types to proof that it can handle multiple agents types.

[image]

Comment: Great solution. Thanks for your effort!

So if I understood correctly, using the "isBlocked" variable did only return a boolean, but didn't actually perform a "block" or "unblock" method?